# Wildfly deployed war file name is not same as fileName in pom.xml

Tags: maven, jakarta-ee, deployment, jboss, wildfly

I am using maven in my project. Whenever i restart server  wildfly deploy my app name as  `SMM-App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` inside wildfly deployment folder. I want to remove version part after artifact. So I want name be like `SMM-APP.war`

Firstly I add fileName property in build. It actually worked when I execute `$ mvn package` command.

```
 <build>
    <finalName>${artifactId}</finalName>
    ...
 </build>
```

How can I change this name during restart of the wildfly? I don't want to manually copy war file and add it to deployment directory everytime.
Any Suggestions?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I solved the problem step by step:

- I deleted deployed `SMM-App-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war` from deployments folder of wildfly.
- Execute `$ mvn clean goal` from terminal inside project root folder.
- Right click on the project in eclipse then select **Maven> Update Project**.
- Clean and restart server from server tab.

I hope it will help to anybody have the same problem.

Comment: I would use the maven plugin to do the deployment, rather than use the deployment directory for your dev environment, unless there is specific need not too. If the reason for the naming is for the url used for web url, you should instead define this properly, not rely on the filename based default

Comment: During development i change code and restart the server many times. Eclipse deploy war file. I don't want to execute "mvn package" command everytime manually. So is there way to passing around this. @WillT